# Division arithmetic in VB.net automatically rounding off

Tags: vb.net, integer, arithmetic-expressions

I have a bit of an issue with the following piece of code.

```
        Dim k As Integer

    k = (TextBox1.Text - 750) \ 250

    MsgBox("There should be " & k & " items")
```

Lets say that textbox1 has a value of 3050 the outcome would be 9.20 however my Mesagebox returns 9 which is not what I want. In fact, I want to see it without the rounding off

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is integer division in VB, so you need to use `/` instead.

See here ([MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx)) for more information on VB operators.

Also, as is mentioned in the comments, you're storing `k` as an integer - use `double` (or whatever) instead.

So, how about:

```
Dim k As Double
Dim tbText as Double
If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, tbText) Then
    k = (tbText  - 750) / 250

    MsgBox("There should be " & k & " items")
End If
```

If you're *certain* that `TextBox1.Text` will be a number, you don't have to use `TryParse`it like I did - but I don't think you should ever trust a user to get it right...

Comment: Basically just used double instead of Integer, and swich forwardslash to backwardslash